# Can I use smart matching, ~~, in Test::More's cmp_ok?

Tags: perl, testing, smartmatch

I am testing a function that returns an array. The array could be different depending on the environment but it will always have at least one constant value (the one that I want to test).

As I am using Perl 5.12, I can use the smartmatch operator to find if the element is in the array:

```
ok($known_value ~~ @returned, 'testing method abc')
```

But I like the enhanced output of `is` and `like` with the "found" and "expected" parts. So I tried this:

```
cmp_ok($known_value, '~~', @returned, 'testing method abc')
```

This does not work because it seems that `cmp_ok` expects a scalar in both parts of the comparison:

```
not ok 1 - testing method abc
#   Failed test 'testing method abc'
#   at abc.t line 53.
#     'stable_value'
#         ~~
#     '2'
```

The array in the "expected" slot is evaluated in scalar context and converted to 2.

I can work around this with a hack using `like` and stringifying the array, but having a test where you can use the smartmatch operator as a comparison method (like `when`) would be nice. Is there a way to do this with Test::More or some other module?

At the moment I am using:

```
ok($known_value ~~ @returned, 'testing method abc')
  or diag (
      "ERROR:\n".
      "Found: ". Dumper @returned."\n".
      "Expected at least one element equal to '$known_value'"
  )
```

Is this the best that I can do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't use `@returned` because of how Perl passes arguments to subroutines. (Arrays are flattened into the argument list and lose their identity.) Pass an array reference instead:

```
cmp_ok($known_value, '~~', \@returned, 'testing method abc')
```

The smart match operator is smart enough to do the right thing. From perlsyn:

> Note that the smart match implicitly
>   dereferences any non-blessed hash or
>   array ref, so the "Hash" and "Array"
>   entries apply in those cases.

Comment: Silly me! Before your editing I look again at the perlsync and I read `Note that the smart match implicitly dereferences any non-blessed hash or array ref, so the "Hash" and "Array" entries apply in those cases`. I have missed that note for all the times that I was looking there: After the first time I read it I always look at the (table)[http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Smart-matching-in-detail] where there is no example with references. Thanks a lot for fixing my overlooking.

Answer (score 3):

[`Test::Deep`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Test%3a%3aDeep) provides many utilities for testing parts of (possibly very deeply nested) structures, and also produces quite useful diagnostics in case of failures. I believe one of its `bag` functions could do the job for you.

```
use Test::Deep;

my @foo = ('bar', 'baz', 'moo');

cmp_deeply(
    \@foo,
    superbagof('baz'),
    '@foo contains at least one "baz"',
);
```

This way you can, if it ever turns out to be necessary, do much more complicated assertions than what smartmatching would allow without having to break things down into much smaller chunks, and will also continue to function on old perls.

Comment: Thanks, Rafl, nice to know this methods. I tried sometime ago Test::Deep->cmp_deeply for comparing two arrays, it was good but Test::More->is_deeply was better for me because I wanted to know where structures start to differ instead telling me they have different number of elements. I will give a more deeper read to documentation to see what I can add to my tool set from this module.

Comment: @Pablo: `cmp_deeply` should tell you where the differences are. Also, `eq_or_diff` from Test::Differences is similar.

Comment: @Pablo: without looking at the source or documentation for `cmp_deeply`, no I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

Automatic dumping with [Test::More](http://p3rl.org/Test%3a%3aMore#explain), [Test::Most](http://p3rl.org/Test%3a%3aMost#show):

```
use Test::More 0.82; diag explain \@returned;

use Test::Most 0.21; show \@returned;
```

Comment: Thanks daxim, I have seen that explain() has been in Test::More since 2008!! Probably I should reread the modules documentation more often to avoid missing nice new features ;-)